# Using transactions in sqlplus

Tags: oracle-11g-r2, transaction, sqlplus

I'm coming to oracle from postgresql.  In postgresql, I can use the command-line tool, psql, to execute a delete or update in a transaction:

```
dbpool.production=> begin;
BEGIN
dbpool.production=*> delete from foo where account_id like '%1000%';
DELETE 9
dbpool.production=*> commit;
COMMIT
dbpool.production=>
```

I like to see that I got the count I expected before committing the transaction.

Things don't work like that in sqlplus, the Oracle command-line tool.  When I type "begin;", it just starts reading more input, never apparently doing anything:

```
SQL> begin;
  2  update opacs_work_orders set customer_id = null;
  3  commit;
  4
```

**How can I, using sqlplus, execute one or more statements with a transaction?**

Comment: In SQL*Plus auto-commit is disabled by default. Just run your DML and then issue a `commit` or `rollback` to end the transaction. It's the same as using `\set AUTCOMMIT off` in `pgsql` (which is the default on all my computers)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You simply don't use `begin` in sqlplus if you're just going to issue a series of SQL queries. You're in a transaction already as soon as you issue some SQL. You can't really be outside of a transaction anyway for practical purposes (sure, if you've just logged in, or just committed and haven't started anything else, well, you're not in a transaction).

A few things to be careful with though:

- sqlplus does have an autocommit setting. It's off by default in modern versions, but just to make sure:

  ```
  SQL> show autocommit
  autocommit OFF
  ```

  If it happens to be on:

  ```
  SQL> set autocommit off
  ```
- sqlplus commits on exit by default even in modern versions. To disable that:

  ```
  SQL> set exitcommit off
  ```

  (That's fairly new, appeared in 11g or 11gR2. Previously always committed on exit.)
- DDL commits. (Twice. Once before, once after.) Note that `truncate` is DDL in Oracle.

Aside from these gotchas, you're in a transaction already when you start sqlplus, and can commit or rollback as you please.

```
$ sqlplus mat

SQL*Plus: Release 12.1.0.2.0 Production on Mon Oct 20 19:51:31 2014
...
SQL> insert into abc values (1) ;

1 row created.

SQL> select count(*) from abc;

  COUNT(*)
----------
         1

SQL> rollback;

Rollback complete.

SQL> select count(*) from abc;

  COUNT(*)
----------
         0
```

You need to use `begin`/`end` when you want to run a PL/SQL block. (The short/single line form for that being `exec`.)

Answer (score 2):

The answer

> You're in a transaction already. You can't really be outside of a transaction anyway.

is not true. By default, an Oracle transaction starts at the first DML (insert/update/delete), and ends with commit/rollback. You can start a transaction manually, with the [SET TRANSACTION](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_10005.htm#SQLRF01705) command, but most people don't.

As for a clearer answer between PG and Oracle:

In Postgres, BEGIN tells PG to start a transaction (otherwise it's in auto-commit). The transaction ends of course on commit/rollback.

In Oracle, BEGIN (or DECLARE) is the [start of a PL/SQL block](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/overview.htm#LNPLS141). The block ends with the END; keyword followed by a / on the next line to tell SQL*Plus to execute the block. The block and transaction are completely separate - you could be in a transaction before you execute the block, or the block could start a transaction by issuing some DML.

In Oracle, if you are not in a transaction, a commit/rollback is essentially a no-op. You can tell if you're in a transaction by

```
SELECT count(*)
  FROM v$session v
  WHERE v.AUDSID = sys_context('userenv','sessionid')
    AND v.TADDR IS NOT NULL;
```

You'll get 1 if you are in a transaction, 0 if not.

Comment: A side note: in Postgres you can turn off autocommit as well and then you don't need `begin` to start a transaction.